# Simple Modules over the Weyl Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, operator-theory, noncommutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero and let $A_1=k\langle x,y| \, xy-yx=1 \rangle$ be the Weyl algebra. Is there a (more or less explicit) possibility of writing down all simple modules over $A_1$ (by which I mean all left $A_1$-modules that have no nontrivial left $A_1$-submodule)?

Comment: Hmm, I like this question. There must be a reasonably detailed answer! The only stuff I can remember about simple modules over simple domains (like $A_1$) is from [this paper by Osofsky](http://mathoverflow.net/a/83540/19965) constructing a simple domain that isn't a $V$-ring. In that paper she exercises fantastic control over the simple modules in her examples, although I don't recall offhand if she actually mentioned a technique to cooking them all up.

Comment: You may want to read Richard Block's paper, "The irreducible representations of $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$ and the Weyl algebra" (Advances in Mathematics, 39, p69-110, 1981).

Comment: thx, I also found R. Block's notes "the irreducible representations of the weyl algebra" useful.